# Spring Boot junit testing secured application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-security

I am using in my application Spring Security OAuth2. When I try to test the service layer with JUnit tests I get this error:

> org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException:
>   An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext

Can you tell me how to fix it?

Here is my Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public class FooServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private FooService service;

    @Test
    public void someTest() {    
        service.findFoo(1L);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check http://www.baeldung.com/oauth-api-testing-with-spring-mvc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `@WithMockUser`

```
@WithMockUser(username = "usertest", password = "password", roles = "USER")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
public class FooServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private FooService service;

    @Test
    public void someTest() {    
        service.findFoo(1L);
    }

}
```